# Foursquare API's - venue searching method - Priority limit vs radius

Tags: search, foursquare

Hi every body,

I have a concept problem. I would like to know how FourSquare looks for venues? (how it segments the search area? are they circles with gradually increasing radius? or a randomly choosing from the asked radius )

.

example:

Limit = 100

radius= 1000

total number of venue exist in this radius = 5000

.

which of these two option is the case? :

1- the result will be the 100 venues in a small circle ( like 100 venue in radius of 150 )

2- the result will be the 100 venues and they are well distributed venues come from a radius of 1000

.

To have an idea about why I'm asking this question, my main problem which I try to solve is:

find a radius of fixed number of venue in different adresses. my objective is to find a density index.

for example in in the center of Toronto we have 100 venues in a 50 meters radius, for the same number of venues, in a smaller city, we reach perhaps a radius of 200 meters.

.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by some estimations but it is good to share the experience:
When we have to request one for radius 100 meter and other for 200 meter, logically we expect that the number of second one be greater than first, which, ***IS NOT*** the case with foursquare.
Some of venue in 100 radiuses won’t be in 200 radiuses. 
So, I did request for 100, 200, 300… 1000. Then joined them all, then removed duplicated. So I have some estimation. But it is not the complete venues ( I checked on google map )